# Left outer join multiple selects

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have the following sql statement, that does exactly what it should:

```
select    C.Company_RecID, C.Contact_RecID, C.First_Name, C.Last_Name,
          C.Title, C.Inactive_Flag, e.Description
FROM            dbo.Contact AS C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Contact_Communication AS e ON C.Contact_RecID = e.Contact_RecID 
                                AND e.Communication_Type_RecID = 1 AND e.Default_Flag = 1
```

However, in `dbo.contact_communication`, the `description` field means different things depending upon the `communication_type_recID`.  If it's `1`, description is an email address.  If it's `4`, it's a cell phone number, if it's `2`, it's a direct number, and if it's `14`, it's a personal cell phone number.

I'd like to change the query to return three additional columns. Column 8 would be the value of description if there is a record for this contact with a recid of 4, column 9 the value of description if there is a record for this contact with a recid of 2, and column 10 if there is a value of 14.

Comment: You can do this with conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be pretty close as I understand what you are looking for.

```
select C.Company_RecID
    , C.Contact_RecID
    , C.First_Name
    , C.Last_Name
    , C.Title
    , C.Inactive_Flag
    , e.Description
    , EmailAddress = MAX(case when communication_type_recID = 1 then e.Description end)
    , CellPhone = MAX(case when communication_type_recID = 4 then e.Description end)
    , DirectNumber = MAX(case when communication_type_recID = 2 then e.Description end)
    , PersonalCellPhone = MAX(case when communication_type_recID = 14 then e.Description end)
FROM dbo.Contact AS C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Contact_Communication AS e ON C.Contact_RecID = e.Contact_RecID 
                                        AND e.Communication_Type_RecID IN (1,2,4,14) 
                                        AND e.Default_Flag = 1
group by C.Company_RecID
    , C.Contact_RecID
    , C.First_Name
    , C.Last_Name
    , C.Title
    , C.Inactive_Flag
    , e.Description
```

Comment: Closer, but this returns multiple records for one hit.
Company_RecID Contact_RecID First_Name Last_Name Title Inactive_Flag Description EmailAddress CellPhone DirectNumber PersonalCellPhone
2543 7428 D G NULL 0 4099995675 NULL NULL 4099995675 NULL
2543 7428 D G NULL 0 D@company.com Davxne@sxers.com NULL NULL NULL

Comment: Well I am mostly guessing because we don't have actual tables or data to work with. I will be happy to update this if you can post ddl and data. Here is a great explanation of that. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: if one contact can has multiple contact_Communication, how many lines you want return?
  you line is contact live, you should remove e.Description from the group by

Comment: I believe that by removing e.description from the select and from the group by, this may have given the desired results.  Will update shortly.

Comment: That would make sense. Wasn't sure if you needed that in the output or not but that makes sense.....duh....sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think UNION might help you. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

You can try something like this:

```
select col_1, 'something' as A, '' as B from TableA
union
select col_2, '' as A, 'something' as B from TableA
```

col_1 and col_2 are actual columns in the table, while A and B are aliases for this extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Without aggregation

```
select C.Company_RecID
     , C.Contact_RecID
     , C.First_Name
     , C.Last_Name
     , C.Title
     , C.Inactive_Flag
     , e.Description
     , e1.Description  as EmailAddress
     , e2.Description  as CellPhone
     , e4.Description  as DirectNumber
     , e14.Description as PersonalCellPhone 
  FROM dbo.Contact AS C 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Contact_Communication AS e1 
    ON e1.Contact_RecID = C.Contact_RecID   
   AND e1.Communication_Type_RecID = 1 
   AND e1.Default_Flag = 1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Contact_Communication AS e2 
    ON e2.Contact_RecID = C.Contact_RecID   
   AND e2.Communication_Type_RecID = 2
   AND e2.Default_Flag = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Contact_Communication AS e4 
    ON e4.Contact_RecID = C.Contact_RecID   
   AND e4.Communication_Type_RecID = 4 
   AND e4.Default_Flag = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Contact_Communication AS e14 
    ON e14.Contact_RecID = C.Contact_RecID   
   AND e14.Communication_Type_RecID = 14  
   AND e14.Default_Flag = 1
```